# Uploading PDF file from Memory Stream to AmazonS3

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-s3, aspose

I am uploading file to AmazonS3 from MemoryStream. This is my scenario
1: User selects a doc(or docx) file to upload then clicks upload button
2: With using Aspose I am converting it to pdf and save it on memory stream
3: Upload file to AmazonS3

The file is uploading successfully,but its getting upload without anytype(ie type of file is just FILE).
This is how I am uploading

```
if(fupload.HasFile){
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(fupload.FileBytes.ToArray());                                                               
MemoryStream outputstream = new MemoryStream();
                                Aspose.Words.Document d1 = new Aspose.Words.Document(memStream);                                
                                d1.Save(outputstream, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf);

                                var client = AmazonHelper.S3Client;
                                var PutReq = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest();
                                var GetReq = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetObjectRequest();
                                PutReq.BucketName = "MyBucket";
                                PutReq.InputStream = outputstream;
                                PutReq.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                                PutReq.Key = "Filename";
                                var Result = client.PutObject(PutReq).ToJson();
                                }
```

I have to save the selected file in stream I can't save it on a physical directory.
Is there any alternate approach to do this?

[image: This is the file I have uploaded, you can see its Type: File] You can see its Type: File.If I rename it to Filename.pdf and open in pdf reader,it will open it correctly

Comment: `but its getting upload without anytype`. Not sure what you mean by that and how are you checking the type?

Comment: specify the extension of the file in your request `PutReq.Key = "Filename.pdf"`

Comment: I have specified in Content-Type

Comment: You are viewing the file information in Windows. Windows checks file extensions for known types and gives you a description accordingly. It does not matter what mime-type you specify, it is how Windows work.